# Solus Linux. Qemu( Boxes Gnome ) (virtual machine) помощь

Tags: linux, qemu, solus

[image: hm]

Ссоздавал две виртуальные машины qemu (точнее в приложении Boxes gnome). Потом удалил, а место не освободилось(проверял в virtual machine manager - занято 40 гигов.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

А в папке по умолчанию искали?

```
~/.local/share/gnome-boxes/images/
```

или тут:

```
/home/user/.var/app/org.gnome.Boxes/data/gnome-boxes/images
```

Или выполните команду:

```
find ~ -size +39G -ls
```

Comment: 1 не подошло, 2-е не нашло, 3-е тоже пустота

Comment: оно как-то память зарезервировало походу, я ведь удалял виртуальные машины, а хранилище для них каким-то образом всё ровно выделяется, хотя я даже пробовал удалять всё.